# how to uninstall older python3.6 from Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: uninstall, python3

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and it comes with python 3.10 installed as `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10`

However, I also have `/usr/local/bin/python3 -> python3.6` .  I think it must be from a previous manual installation of python.

How to uninstall this python 3.6 ? Or is that a bad idea?

When I do

`sudo apt-get remove python3`

it asks me to confirm, but I can't tell from the preceding printout which of the two versions it is going to remove.  The older version is first in `$PATH`.  How do I ensure that it is (only) the older version that will get removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files in `/usr/local/` (including your python 3.6 in `/usr/local/bin`) **cannot** be removed by apt.

You did not install files in `/usr/local/bin` using apt. You installed them some other way. How you uninstall them best depends upon how you installed them.

Many non-apt install methods include uninstall instructions. If you can find those instructions, follow them.

If you cannot locate uninstall instructions, and since you did not use apt to install, you can likely use plain old `rm` on files in `/usr/local/`

Comment: OK, that's what the AI overlord says :) but I am just afraid to ```rm``` some installation by hand.  Should I not be afraid?

Comment: ...and when you are afraid, you do things carefully. Controlled. With tests. Double-checking. Without wildcards. The usual precautions.

Comment: @MarkGaleck If you are worried about removing the files, you can start by `mv`'ing them to a backup directory. If something breaks, you move them back.